# "Invalid input image - format must be in ['RGBA', 'LA', 'L'], got RGB." iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, openai-api

I am using the OpenAI "Create Image Edit" API [link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/images/create-edit). My mask image is [maskImage.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1do4QTq3grnUq8WvgCMfiy5LZUkPpQ_Wn/view).

After calling the API, when the response comes, I have got the error:

> Invalid input image - format must be in ['RGBA', 'LA', 'L'], got RGB."

How can I change the PNG image format as ['RGBA', 'LA', 'L'] in iOS Swift?

I have found a solution in JavaScript, *[How to validate an image before sending to DALL E API with front-end JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74810022/how-to-validate-an-image-before-sending-to-dall-e-api-with-front-end-javascript/74810023#74810023)*. But I can not find a solution in iOS.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why not fix the format of the image so it's in the correct format? Then you don't need to change any code.

Comment: @HangarRash, editing portion of mask image must be transparent according to doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add opacity/alpha to the `UIImage`/`pngData`.

```
extension UIImage {
    var hasAlpha: Bool {
        guard let alphaInfo = self.cgImage?.alphaInfo else {return false}
        return alphaInfo != CGImageAlphaInfo.none &&
            alphaInfo != CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst &&
            alphaInfo != CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast
    }
}
```

Is a quick way to check if a `UIImage` has alpha.

You can add alpha with

```
extension UIImage {

    func imageWithAlpha(alpha: CGFloat) throws -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        draw(at: CGPointZero, blendMode: .normal, alpha: alpha)
        guard let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else{
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            throw ImageError.unableToAddAplhaToImage
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
    enum ImageError: LocalizedError{
        case unableToAddAplhaToImage
    }
}
```

1 being a dark image and 0 being a transparent image, OpenAI is looking for 0.

The method above will change the entire `UIImage`, if you use this the entire image will be replaced.

A mask will only have sections of an image that have a value of 0.

The PNG you are showing doesn't show any pixels as zero.

In short, with the code above `if image.hasAlpha == false` you will get the error you are talking about when you submit.

if `if image.hasAlpha == true` then it is ok with OpenAI.

In javascript you can use Jimp to simplify the whole thing, you can do all the checks in just a few lines.

[Dall E API error: "Invalid input image - format must be in ['RGBA', 'LA', 'L'], got RGB."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74773173/dall-e-api-error-invalid-input-image-format-must-be-in-rgba-la-l/75686551#75686551)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Mask image should be transparent, otherwise got that error.

Comment: @symon the question is a bit open ended and with swift usually you can post some code so people can reproduce the OpenAI API is not designed to be used in the iOS side (it shouldn’t be). I have this code because I check everything before touching my server. When I first implemented it I spent a good 3 days getting it all connected since Node.js isn’t my strong area. This was one of the errors I was getting.